# Вывод последних 5 цифр из числа

Tags: sql

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести в селект последние 5 цифр в числе?

Comment: Запросите соответствующий остаток.

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: @Sergey4590, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT substr(CAST(12345321 AS VARCHAR(50)),-5) FROM DUAL;
```

P.S. Если вы хотите получить решение для Оракла, то указываете в тегах Оракл.

Answer (score 0):

```
dividend % divisor
```

Оператор `%` - находит остаток от деления чисел.

Для вашего случая `dividend % 100000`
Т.е. делим на число с n нулями, чтобы получить n последних цифр. Например, чтобы получить 2 последних числа от 234 - `234 % 100`, что будет равно 34.

Comment: в Oracle не работает!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MOD(N, 100000) FROM DUAL;
```